# Selecting second anchor element within lists using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a list of anchor tags and have to test clicking the 2nd tag in the list.

```
<ul id="shortcuts">
    <li><a ui-sref="app.journeyExplorer" href="#/journey-explorer/"><span class="ng-binding">1</span></a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="app.userGroupManager" href="#/user-group-manager"><span class="ng-binding">2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

After much investigation and testing reached at the conclusion that the correct statement should be:

```
element(By.id('shortcuts')).element(By.tagName('a')).get(1).click();
```

But it shows undefined. If I use get() it doesn't work. without get it clicks the 1st anchor tag in the list with a warning: 'More than one anchor tag found, in such case the 1st one is selected'

Can someone please help out with this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to try selector below (note `all()` instead of second `element()` to match all anchors (so that `.get()` that comes next makes any sense.

```
element(By.id('shortcuts')).all(By.tagName('a')).get(1).click();
```

or via .css

```
element(By.css('#shortcuts a:nth-child(1)').click();
```

Comment: Can you please share how you can put a code in question without executing it ?

Comment: Use four space characters in front of every line. There's also a button in the editor when you write a question / answer.

Comment: FYI, the `nth-child` approach will not work here.  Both `a` elements are the 1st child of their parent.  You would need to do `#shortcuts li:nth-child(2) a`.