# Protractor Failed: browser.findElements(...).all is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

First time trying to e2e test my AngularJS application.

I have an ul with the class 'meta'. The ul has a couple of li's.
I want to grab the first li and compare that to a string.

```
var duration = browser.findElements(by.className('meta')).all(by.tagName('li')).get(1);
```

But when running the test i keep getting the error:  Failed: browser.findElements(...).all is not a function.

I already tried findElement and findElements and keep getting the same error.

I stumbled upon this previous question: [Selecting second anchor element within lists using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648203/selecting-second-anchor-element-within-lists-using-protractor). But it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use the "default" ElementFinder syntax of Protractor, that is for example `element(by.css('ul'))`, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder)

You will then get this

`var duration = element(by.className('meta')).all(by.tagName('li')).get(1);`

Or `element.all(by.css('.meta li')).first();`, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all)

Or the shorthand `$$('.meta li')).first();`, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$$)

Comment: Thanks very much! Do you know why my code didn't work. Besides the browser. it isn't very different

Answer (score 7):

The currently accepted answer is correct in terms of what you should be using, but here is why your code did not work.

Protractor, as you may know, wraps the `WebDriverJS` - selenium javascript bindings. On top of what is there, it adds a lot of convenient concepts like `ElementFinder` or `ElementArrayFinder` or the `browser` object.

*Protractor also provides you a way to call the pure `WebDriverJS` functions and methods directly*, like, for example, it allows to use `findElement()` or `findElements()` on the `browser` object.

In your case, the `browser.findElements(by.className('meta'))` would return an array of `WebElement`s which is a pure `WebDriverJS` concept. Note, this is not an `ElementArrayFinder` instance, you are not at the Protractor territory at this point.

Now, you are trying to call `.all()` function on this array of elements and it obviously fails.

The Protractor way of doing this would be:

```
var duration = $$('.meta li').first();
```

Or, you can even get away with a single selector:

```
var duration = $('.meta li:first-of-type');
```

Related reading:

- [Protractor Syntax vs WebDriverJS Syntax](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/7da9c3a910bb000b30bf9ba82ef48c64bd751709/docs/webdriver-vs-protractor.md)

Comment: Hi @alecxe , Can you help me to learn advance protractor. Deeper into protractor. How each promise work, some useful links of github for protractor for advance learning. My question is broad but whatever you can provide me with links to study some advance concepts of protractor.

Comment: @KishanPatel the [Protractor documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) is actually a good place to start. But, don't dive into too much theory - just go out there and automate things :) Practice, practice!

Comment: Yes. Protractor Documentation is really easy to understand. I have been doing practical stuffs only as you said. Apart from that any other important Document/repository at github ?