# How to use nth-child to click on an <li> where all the <li>s have the same class in Protractor / Angular test?

Tags: angular, css-selectors, protractor

I am trying to click the 3rd link in a Protractor test of my Angular app:

[image: screen_grab]

Below is my attempt:

```
 it('should click the Calculators menu button', () => {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var calculator_button = element(by.css('ul li:nth-child(3)'));
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(calculator_button), 5000);
    calculator_button.click();
});
```

But I get the below error message:

> Failed: Wait timed out after 5004ms

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make to the above method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting second anchor element within lists using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648203/selecting-second-anchor-element-within-lists-using-protractor)

Comment: Hi @cjd82187 Thanks for your link, I've made some progress with the issue. I've updated my code above based on the answer in the link you provided, but still facing an issue clicking a specific list item.

Comment: I don't know anything about protractor, but the `<li>` element doesn't have a click event on it that I can see.  I'm guessing Protractor does not know about how you are creating the interaction.

Comment: right, a click should be called against `a`, `button`, `input` elements. Otherwise you need to inject a script in the browser console if you still want to click

Comment: right now I'm confused what is your probelm. looks like you're having 3 at the same time, and you were able to solve the first one. if it's the case you need to create another question

Comment: So I think you can also use xpath for this: let say you want a specific link, `let index = 1`. Then you can write a locator string as `let locator = "(//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav pull-right navigation']//li)[index]/a`. This will go the link in `a` tag of your choice.

Comment: Hi @SergeyPleshakov I am able to click the link using XPath, but I want to avoid using XPath, so I'm looking for another  way to locate the link

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what I said in the comment, click may not work if the element is not visible. Lets say you first `li` is on the page, the second is kind of below. In this case you need to scroll to it

PS

Answering your question `How to use nth-child to click on an <li> where all the <li>s have the same class`

## answer

declare a function that returns you specific element like this

```
let specificLi = function(i) {
  return element(by.css('li:nth-child(' + i + ')'))
}
```

or the same thing

```
let specificLi = i => $('li:nth-child(' + i + ')');
```

and then use it

```
await specificLi(1).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to apply this to my code (I've updated my question with my latest attempt). Would you be able to point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: honestly there might be 100 of reasons... first find out if the element `isPresent`